# React.js Setting State Modifies Website scale

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

when my component re-renders itself after `setState();` it seems to set the wrong scale for the page and all the content seems to fall off the side, it looks like the HTML and CSS has got the wrong screen size, and therefore the images, text, and boxes don't fit the screen, this isn't an issue with my CSS breakpoints or anything but I don't understand what I need to do since i've never seen this before

Before re-render:
[image: Before Re-render]

after re-render:
[image: after rendering]

MoviesHome.js

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        slideUpClass: ['movieFullTabContainer', 'movieFullTabContainerClosed'],
        isOpen: 0,
};    
handleMovieClick = () => {
        if(this.state.isOpen === 0){
            this.setState({isOpen: 1});
        }else{
            this.setState({isOpen: 0});
        }
}
...

<div className='rowsContainer'>
    <div className='rowContent'>
        {this.state.Trending != null ? <MoviesRow clickHandler={this.handleMovieClick} name={'For You'} index={0} movies={this.state.Trending}/> : ''}
        {this.state.Trending != null ? <MoviesRow clickHandler={this.handleMovieClick} name={'Trending'} index={1} movies={this.state.Trending}/> : ''}
    </div>
</div>

<MovieSlideUp clickHandler={this.handleMovieClick} slideupClass={this.state.slideUpClass[this.state.isOpen]}/>
```

MoviesRow.js

```
<div key={Math.random(0, 1000)} onClick={() => this.props.clickHandler()} className='sliderItem'>
    <img className='sliderImg' src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/${this.props.movies[i].poster_path}`} alt=''></img>
    <div className='movieOverlayContainer'>
        <div className='movieOverlayContainerContent'>
            <p className='movieTitle'>{this.props.movies[i].title}</p>
            <p>{this.props.movies[i].release_date.substring(0,4)}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

MovieFullTab.js

```
import CircleSVG from './SVG/Circle-Solid.svg';
import StarSVG from './SVG/Star-Solid.svg';
import HeartSVG from './SVG/Heart-Solid.svg';
import PlaySVG from './SVG/Play-Solid.svg';

...

<div id={this.props.slideupClass}>
    <div onClick={() => this.props.clickHandler()} id='fullscreenTabContainer'>
        <div id='fullscreenSurroundingContainer'>
            <div id='fullscreenContent'>
                <div id='movieInfoContainer'>
                    <div id='movieImageContainer'>
                        <img src='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/jTswp6KyDYKtvC52GbHagrZbGvD.jpg'></img>
                    </div>
                    <div id='movieFullInfoContainer'>
                        <p id='movieFullInfoTitle'>Luca</p>
                        <p className='movieFullInfoText'>15</p>
                        <p className='movieFullInfoText'>2021</p>
                        <div id='fullGenreContainer'>
                            <p>Adventure</p>
                            <img alt='' className='seperator-side' src={CircleSVG}></img>
                            <p id='secondGenre'>Comedy</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id='movieFullRatingsContainer'>
                            <img id='featuredStarIcon' alt='' src={StarSVG}></img>
                            <p>8.6</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id='fullMovieInfoOverviewContainer'>
                            <p>Luca and his best friend Alberto experience an unforgettable summer on the Italian Riviera.
                            But all the fun is threatened by a deeply-held secret: they are sea monsters from another
                            world just below the water’s surface</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id='movieFullInfoButtonsContainer'>
                            <div id='movieFullInfoLikeButton'>
                                <img alt='' src={HeartSVG}></img>
                            </div>
                            <div id='movieFullInfoPlayButton'>
                                <p>Watch</p>
                                <img alt='' src={PlaySVG}></img>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

MoviesRow.css

```
.rowTopContainer{
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
}

.ArrowButtonImage{
    filter: invert(65%) sepia(5%) saturate(170%) hue-rotate(169deg) brightness(84%) contrast(82%);
}

.flippedArrow{
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.buttonSlideContainer{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.ButtonSlide:first-child{
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.ButtonSlide{
    width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.movieRowTitleContainer{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.movieRowTitle{
    color: white;
    font-family: Bold;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.viewAllButtonContainer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.viewAllButtonContainer:hover p {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.viewAllButtonContainer p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.moviesRowSliderContainer{
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.sliderItemContent:hover .movieOverlayContainer{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
}

.sliderImg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.movieOverlayContainerContent{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
}

.movieOverlayContainerContent p:nth-child(2){
    font-size: 1vw;
}

.movieTitle{
    font-size: 1.4vw;
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: Bold;
}

.movieShortInfoContainer{
    margin-top: auto;
}

.movieShortInfoContent{
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: auto;
}

.movieShortInfoContent p:not(:first-child) {
    /* margin-left: 15px; */
    font-size: 0.9vw;
}

.movieShortInfoContent p:nth-child(3){
    margin-left: 0;
}

.movieShortInfoContent p:nth-child(2){
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.movieStarIcon{
    height: 15px;
    filter: invert(68%) sepia(95%) saturate(406%) hue-rotate(359deg) brightness(104%) contrast(88%);
}

.userRatingsContainer{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.movieOverlayContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.sliderItem{
    width: 19%;
    height: auto;
    flex:none;
    position: relative;
}

.sliderItemContent{
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
    .sliderItem{
        width: 18%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .sliderItem{
        width: 38%;
    }

    .movieOverlayContainerContent p:nth-child(2){
        font-size: 1.8vw;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .movieTitle{
        font-size: 3vw;
    }
}
```

I Hope the code helps :)

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code? We can't really help debug code if we can't see what it's doing.

Comment: sure, thing, kind of useless without code

Comment: I would think it ***is*** related to any CSS/styling being applied to your UI. Can you inspect various parts of the DOM in your browser's dev tools to see what changes (before & after) when state is updated? You might also not want to use a random number for your React keys (`key={Math.random(0, 1000)}`) they don't persist render to render so you'll always rerender the entire array, and I don't think the random function takes 2 args.

Comment: yep, it seems it is, something to do with the `MoviesRow.js` component style pushing the page right., The random I know is bad I'm planning on changing on that, I would've thought random takes 2 args, i guess not, thanks for the help!

Comment: You write about possible css problem but you don't show them. How does your css look like?

Comment: I have fixed it now, my `MoviesRow.css` has been added to the question, it was the `display: flex;` that was pushing the slider items right, and therefore the page wasn't scaling since it's blocked by the flex container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simply the `display: flex;` container pushing the container, props to Drew Reese for helping resolve the issue... Thanks :)